# Javascript understanding array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was reading about understanding arrays in another link, but still stuck..

[JavaScript Storing Data in 2-D Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041858/javascript-storing-data-in-2-d-array)

[Javascript Appending to 2-D Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353731/javascript-appending-to-2-d-array)

[understanding nested arrays in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374480/understanding-nested-arrays-in-javascript)

The problem is, i have sample code that i want to learn, but when i did in different style(cz different situation), i got stuck. The sample problem is like : (uses f12 in browser to check console)

[image]

It looks different, but when i check inside it's the same..

[image]

Both arrays are created in different ways, the first one is (i want to make this) :

```
var datas = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

And the other array (my own method) :

```
mydatas=[];
```

and how i add this elements to this array is:

```
mydatas.push(newArr);
```

And my half code to compare it : (many other thing to do, but didnt connect to this problem)

```
var datas = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
var mydatas=[];
for(i=0;i<Oldarry.length;i++){
    //other proccess
    newArr = [address, latlng.lat(), latlng.lng(), (index+1)];
    mydatas.push(newArr);
}

console.log(datas);
console.log(datas[0]);
console.log(mydatas);
console.log(mydatas[0]);
```

The result is :

[image]

My question is **how I could create the first array** (*datas*). Thanks for any help. 
*The strange in *mydatas* i can't access first array, but in second picture if i click in console there are 7 array inside..

my full code without api key: https://jsfiddle.net/n425qxgy/

Comment: Please post the code you attempted with input examples

Comment: my real input is excel spreadsheet, can i ask, how i can upload it ? thq for reply..

Comment: Make a [mcve] using csv for example. `var data = \`a,b,c,d\ne,f,g,h\``

Comment: thanks, i need really patient, to solve my problem with creating my model question.. little pain.. hehe

Comment: when creating the model question, i understand the problem is in my array, and after some search, i found that is real problem, check the accept answer, btw thanks for help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing the same tests in Chrome or Firefox? I am guessing you are using IE/Edge since you pressed F12. It could be a funny issue with the MS console which is treating adding to an array differently....but the same.

Comment: yep this is my problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175017/google-chrome-console-log-inconsistency-with-objects-and-arrays bacause my _other proccess_ is more longer than next code, js execute my next progress meanwhile _other proccess_ still unfinished..

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't understand what exactly you want? I hope this could help you

```js
var datas = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
var mydatas=[];
for(i=0;i<datas.length;i++){
mydatas.push(datas[i]);
}
console.log(datas);
console.log(datas[0]);
console.log(mydatas);
console.log(mydatas[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yeah that's is my code, but i got different result, check my experiment..

Comment: btw, can you help me, what i must add to more easy to understand in my question,, thq for help..

Comment: you could use snippet for more detail ,edit your question and add snippet